# How to fix material-kit-react 'module not found: webpack loader error'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, create-react-app

I want to implement [material-kit-react](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/#/documentation/tutorial) into a react project. I keep running into some kind of webpack error when I try to access its components through the npm package.

***Full error:***

```
./node_modules/material-kit-react/src/components/CustomButtons/Button.jsx 51:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   });
|   return (
>     <Button {...rest} ref={ref} className={btnClasses}>
|       {children}
|     </Button>
```

***The error is coming from this code:***

```
import React from 'react';
import RegularButton from 'material-kit-react/src/components/CustomButtons/Button'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RegularButton>Default</RegularButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Here is my package.json file:***

```
{
  "name": "material-ui-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "material-kit-react": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm almost positive that the error is coming from the fact that the files from the material-kit-react npm package are .jsx instead of .js, but I could be misunderstanding the issue. I would really like to fix this issue without ejecting from create-react-app. I don't have any experience with configuring my own webpack file but any advice would be useful. Thanks.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126982/react-material-kit-component-not-supporting-jsx) asked but was never answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATED:

I decided to email the Creative Tim Staff about changing the material-kit-react npm package to use .js files instead of .jsx for compatibility with create-react-app and gatsby.js starters. They have now fixed this issue. Here is the updated link to the new [material-kit-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-kit-react).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a problem in your `webpack.config.js` file. For resolving `.jsx` files your `module.export` section should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/assets/frontend/main.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app/assets/javascripts',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Pay attention to `resolve` section.

Comment: I have a SPFx project, but i cannot locate/see webpack.config.js in any of my folders. how can i create this?

Comment: @Aventus honestly I never used SPFx but in majority of situation we should define this file on the top level of our project.
I made a little research and found this in Microsoft's official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/extending-webpack-in-build-pipeline
Also, I found this sample of SPFx project with webpack you can try it https://github.com/peerigon/markdown-loader/tree/master/example

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks for this helpful info. Also, the 2nd link you shared seems not to be the link for the SPFx project with webpack.

Would you know what loader should I use for my case where I want to use a .js file for my typescript project? here's a link to my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103169/cannot-use-js-file-in-a-react-tsx-project/67103777#67103777