# cannot use .js file in a react tsx project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spfx, tsx

So I have a typescript project (.tsx) this is actually a SharePoint Framework project (SPFx) but decided to post it here since this involves typescript in general.

My main file is a .tsx, and I have a component that is created in .JS (.js file extension). I want to import this component to my project, however, I am faced with an issue

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:4)
> File was processed with these loaders:
> ./node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js
> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

How can I import or use a .js component in my .tsx react project without converting the .js to tsx?

based on the error, it seems I need additional loaders, what should I do? thank you!

Here's my tsconfig
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your *tsconfig.json* file with

```
...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
...
```

so you basically add a *allowJs* property to *compilerOptions* object in your *tsconfig.json* file.

Comment: Thanks however, I've done this, but there's an error:
 error TS5053: Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'. I have also tried. I also need to have declaration: true

Comment: @Aventus can you copy and paste the whole of your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: added tsconfig screenshot in the post

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Comment: It does not work